# SciPy ignores inequality constraints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimize

I am using scipy (SLSQP method) for structural optimization (SciPy Version 1.6.1).
For each part, I have 13 design variables but only one used for the cost function (mass) - the other ones exist to fulfill certain inequality constraints. Since I do not know in the beginning, how many parts (PIDs) are to be optimized, I generate the optimization using iterators.

I define some inequality constraints as smooth functions because they describe the feasible domain, but also some inequality constraints that are defined as numpy arrays using a Taylor approximation:

```
def generate_ineq_list(PID_list,x,crit_list):
    ineq_list = []

    for i in np.arange(len(PID_list)):
        f01 = -2*x[i*13]**2 + x[i*13+2] + 1
        ...
        f25 = 4*(x[i*13+9] + 1)*(x[i*13+1] + 1) - (x[i*13+1] + 1)**4 - 3*(x[i*13+5])**2

        ineq_list.append([f01,...,f25])

        V1A = x[i*13]
        V3A = x[i*13+2]
        V1D = x[i*13+8]
        V3D = x[i*13+10]
        H   = x[i*13+12]

        # Now iterating over all defined criteria (crit), parts (PID) and variables to 
        # set up a Taylor approximation.
        # The values with _0 denote the last starting point resp. the point where 
        # the gradients were calculated using the finite difference method. These values 
        # are taken from a pandas dataframe which is dispensed here for the 
        # sake of visibility

        SF = -2.0 + results_old[crit]['sf'].values + \
                gradient[PID]['V1A'][crit]['sf'] * (V1A - V1A_0) + \
                gradient[PID]['V3A'][crit]['sf'] * (V3A - V3A_0) + \
                gradient[PID]['V1D'][crit]['sf'] * (V1D - V1D_0) + \
                gradient[PID]['V3D'][crit]['sf'] * (V3D - V3D_0) + \
                gradient[PID]['H'][crit]['sf'] * (H - H_0)

        ineq_list.append(list(SF))

    ineq_list_flattended = list(itertools.chain(*ineq_list))
    return ineq_list_flattened
```

The result for f01 is a float while the result for SF is a numpy array (which is turned into a list). So what I did was to set up a list where the results are stored to (a list of lists) and then finally flattened into a single list with only floats. This list is then returned to the optimizer as inequality constraint:

```
ineq_functions = lambda x: np.array(generate_ineq_list(self.PID_list,x,crit_list))
ineq_cons = {'type' : 'ineq',
             'fun' : ineq_functions,
            }
```

Now when I execute the optimizer with

```
res = minimize(cost_function_f_,
               x0,
               method='SLSQP',
               constraints = [ineq_cons,
                              eq_cons],
               options = {'ftol' : 1e-9,
                          'disp' : True,
                          'iprint':2,
                           },
               bounds = bounds,
               )
```

I can observe that the first 25 equations (f01-f25) of the inequality constraints are within their domain, but the values of SF are invalid, for instance they have values of e.g. -0.9.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, not considering, misunderstanding?

Any help and/or ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is my first post so I tried to keep everything as basic and simple as possible, I hope I did it right :)

Comment: I don't see a `cost_function_f_` or `x0` definition (not `eq_cons` either), so can't test your code.  And the `ineq_cons` is probably overly complicated - unless that complication is part of the problem.  It certainly doesn't invite study!